# Is there any way to enter password for RunAs on psexec session?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-server-2012-r2, psexec

I'm currently working on an installer script that uses remote sessions with Psexec.exe, I'm trying to run RunAs command on Psexec session and the session getting exit status 1 right after prompt the password.

Currently, the installer suppose to run on Windows Server 2012 r2 with PSv4.0

```
PS C:\> psexec \\Some IP -u <Username> -p <Password> cmd /c runas /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /k <Path for batch file>"

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Enter the password for Administrator:
cmd exited on 192.168.0.124 with error code 1.
```

For some reason, the Psexec doesn't wait for password type just throws the session and gives Error Code 1.
Help will be happily received

Comment: Any reason you don't set up PowerShell remoting instead of making PowerShell launch psexec which launches cmd which launches runas which launches a batch file? It's not really surprising that the ability to redirect stdin reliably gets lost along the way somewhere.

Comment: There's any different approach you are suggesting?

Comment: If remoting is not already set up on the target machine, you can use `winrm quickconfig` (which can be executed with `psexec` if necessary) to set it up, then use `Invoke-Command` to run commands remotely. This supports the use of custom credentials, and you can use `Get-Credential` locally without the need for `runas`. If the command must run with a local logon (that is, it won't work if passed through remoted credentials because it needs to access Windows Installer or network resources or somesuch) you can use Task Scheduler to set up a one-time use job and invoke that.

Comment: I've already read about this matter with the Task Scheduler and this approach isn't for the benefit of my installer. The script that I'm trying to run needs to be running under administrator user, I have the Username & password for that user but when trying to run it from the command line I'm getting UAC popup, I'm trying to work around that without any success. There's any other approach you are suggesting? Thanks for the comment.